# gives a 404 response when using /admin on the url

Tags: laravel

I have a problem when using /admin on the url, if I use it always gives a 404 response but, when I change /admin on web.php in other words like adnnin etc. there was no problem
here piece web.php

```
Route::middleware('isadmin')->group(function () {    
  Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {

        Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'index']);
    
    });
});
```

here my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index () {
        return view('pages.admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have an `admin` folder in `public`?

Comment: @lagbox yes :), my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do not have a folder named `admin` in your `public` directory. The webserver will look for folder/files before falling back to handing the request off to the front loader `public/index.php`, the Laravel application.